# Read requests waiting on finished stream

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm using [pngjs](https://github.com/niegowski/node-pngjs) to read and write some PNGs. I'm getting this error periodically:

```
Error: There are some read requests waiting on finished stream
    at ChunkStream._end (/home/mbayazit/qatools/pdiff/node_modules/pngjs/lib/chunkstream.js:107:13)
    at ChunkStream.end (/home/mbayazit/qatools/pdiff/node_modules/pngjs/lib/chunkstream.js:94:14)
    at PNG.end (/home/mbayazit/qatools/pdiff/node_modules/pngjs/lib/png.js:105:18)
    at ReadStream.onend (_stream_readable.js:483:10)
    at ReadStream.g (events.js:175:14)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:910:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

But it doesn't give me a line-number inside my program.

I only deal with streams in a few places though, they are:

```
fs.createReadStream(oldScreen).pipe(new PNG).on('parsed', function() {
    promises[0].resolve(this);
});

fs.createReadStream(newScreen).pipe(new PNG).on('parsed', function() {
    promises[1].resolve(this);
});
```

And

```
result.png.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(diffName));
```

The three filenames are never the same, so they shouldn't be reading/writing to the same place. I suppose it's possible that a stream did not get closed properly from a previous failed run though. Is there a way I can force all the streams to close nicely?

Comment: You may want to check the documentation for the `PNG` class. My guess is that there's something in there (since the callstack gets interesting at `PNG.end`). Specifically, your problem may be in the lifespan of the `PNG` instance you are creating (`.pipe(new PNG)`), perhaps it needs a `.close()` or something.

Comment: The flow of the program is that it uses the selenium webdriver to save a screenshot of my webpage as a PNG and then I use PNGJS to read and manipulate it. I think the problem might be that I used `fs.writeFile` instead of `fs.writeFileSync`, so it's trying to read the PNG before it's finished writing. It probably only takes a couple milliseconds to write, so the error only occurs when the reader gets ahead of the writer. The problem snuck up on me because I was previously piping it straight to PNGJS without saving it do disk first.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Use [`longjohn`](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn), it may be able to provide with line numbers inside your code. (The exception happens in an async block, so your stack trace does not contain your program, it only stacks with the tick handler in the V8 main loop).
2. It seems like the problem is that someone is trying to *read* from a stream that has just "ended" (was closed, or has reached its end and the underlying layer signaled "end").

Comment: longjohn threw the exception this time but it still didn't give any more information; no line number. The only one reading the file stream should be PNGJS itself.... could be a bug in the library, not sure. Edit: I think I might know what the problem is.

Comment: @Mark: I have been receiving the same error. And cannot seem to stop receiving it every time i run a script that worked just fine until I hit Control C. Did you ever solve the problem?

Comment: @Mark: Here's what think is happening. My script opens a folder of files and adds new data to the files and and then saves them back to the folder. When I hit Control-C, a bunch of the files were saved in some corrupted manner. Whenever I ran the script again, it could not read the data from the corrupted files and an error occurred. Thus the error message "There are some read requests waiting on finished stream" can be taken to mean "could not read file".