# "Using" block in JavaScript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In C# you can use `using` blocks to ensure an object gets cleaned up, even if there's an exception inside the block.

I would like to the same thing in my Node.js app.

It crashes periodically, and I believe this is causing my file streams to not get closed correctly.

I don't think I can wrap everything in a try/catch due to its asynchronous nature; the crash occurs outside of my application code, and my script isn't even anywhere in the callstack.

Is there something akin to `using` blocks so that I can sure everything gets cleaned up nicely?

Comment: I think you want to look into the Domain and Cluster modules, which are still pretty new. They let you put together something reminiscent of an Erlang OTP server setup, though less robust. (caution: I am not a Node expert)

Comment: `using` is translated into `try/finally` by the C# compiler, I don't think it actually solves the asynchrony problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx. Could you provide a little more detail on why the app crashes? Might be able to suggest another solution.

Comment: @ZacharyYates: Ah.. I didn't know `using` worked that way. I asked a more app-specific question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18748023/65387